# sslstrip not stripping any redirected traffic

Tags: penetration-test, sslstrip

I am using the following configuration to set up sslstrip

```
sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 666
sudo arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.199 192.168.1.1

new TERMINAL

sudo sslstrip -l 666
```

The device I'm listening to is my android cellphone. I have tried reinstalling the broswer on my phone to remove caches and going to sites like "http://paypal.com" to force redirection. When the redirection to "https://paypal.com" occurs sslstrip says nothing. It just says its running. I tried it on my laptop and on a windows machine too with no luck. I have used Firefox, safari, IE and Chrome; I know HSTS can be a problem with firefox and chrome. Any ideas?

Wireshark:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the middle of the victim and the router? Basically, are u able to sniff traffic from the victim to the router? And when you access paypal.com, does the site render?

Comment: @Aatif Well I ran dsniff on the wlan interface while running `arpspoof` . I went to websites on the target and no traffic was picked up, so I guess I am not in the middle.

Comment: I also tried Wireshark and added what it picked up.

Comment: You might wanna check if the ARP spoofing worked first.

Comment: Check this tutorial, see if this is helpful: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-conduct-simple-man-middle-attack-0147291/

Comment: @Aatif I tried the tutorial with SSH instead of ftp. I wasn't able to capture any passwords. I also tried using ettercap's  ARP poisoning and when I used chk_poisoning  it said that it wasn't working. However I was able to spoof a DNS request, but it didn't send the request to the ip I wanted it to spoof. So I'm not really sure if I am in the middle.

Comment: what network card are you using, does it have packet injection capabilities?

Comment: I have one that does. I might of tried it already. I'll try it again.

Comment: are you certain of that? which card is it?

Comment: It's the Alfa AWUS036H

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24442/discussion-between-aatif-and-dylan7).